# Redirect output to one file and errors to another in Unix

Tags: unix

Let's say I have a command called "enjoy." I'm expecting enjoy to give valid output and an error message. How do I call enjoy such that the valid output goes to one file and the error messages go to another file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enjoy > log.txt 2> errors.txt
```

Assuming of course that you've used STDOUT and STDERR properly and you're using a nice shell. If you're using csh, you need to do something more complicated:

```
(enjoy > log.txt) >& errors.txt
```

This works because `>&` redirects both STDOUT and STDERR - but STDOUT has already been redirected. The parentheses make sure that STDOUT is long gone before the data gets anywhere near the overzealous `>&`.

Comment: Assuming you use a sane shell - Bourne, Korn, Bash or any other similar more-or-less POSIX compliant shell.  If you use a C Shell derivative, you may have a much harder time managing this.

Comment: Here's my command: (RNAsubopt -s < TestSequences.txt > SubOptTestSequences.txt) >& dummy.txt
sh: Syntax error: Bad fd number

Comment: Which shell are you using?  That looks like a Bourne shell error - it was expecting a number after the `>&`.  Typing `echo $SHELL` may illuminate - but if it says `/bin/sh` then we may need to look at the to see whether that is really Bourne shell or whether it is a link to `bash` or some other shell.  You tagged `unix`; which version of Unix are you running on?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10's default shell. I believe it's bash.

Comment: Yep that's bash. Try my first example that should work for you.